# AngularJS interview questions/challenge

Tags: javascript, angularjs, responsive-design

I got assigned to interview an AngularJS developer with some know-how in responsive design.

Since I like my developers to program during interview, I was thinking on creating a challenge where we can work on together for <1h and then to post the results so I can see them also using my phone/tablet.

1. Any good AngularJS interview questions/challenges out there?
2. Is there a service that allows me to do it easily? push the code and view it on my phone browser. - plnkr has an embedded mode but dont know how good it is..

Answer (score 2):

Good challange will be to create one directive that will do some small responsive UI element. Like a tooltip that will look differently on desktop and browser and will show up differently (on touch and on hover). The person will need to create html template, small resposive css and javascript to hook it up.

I recently needed to create directive like this that will follow the mouse on hover and be static on mobile (but it didn't have responive css - your challange can include that too - have different looking style on a phone).

You can prepare base html that this should work on

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <span tooltop="item.description" tooltop-options="{color: item.color}">
       {{item.text}}
   </span>
</div>
```

It shouldn't take long to create one UI element. If it will be created too fast you can add next challange to create second small directive that will need to exchange data with previous directive (you should not say that he need to create service). it can be directive that render error messages like:

```
<errors/>
```

error messages can be responsive using css, so they look nice on mobile and on desktop.

and one directive that have

```
<something ng-model="someobject"/>
```

and that something directive need to send error message to error directive for instance if object type is not array.

The person will need to create directive that use ngModel and service that will contain errors and second directive that will render message from error service.

Comment: Would be nice to a jsfiddle of the directive.

Comment: @FutuToad if you don't know how to create directive like that, you shouldn't be testing other people. The OP question was about how to test Angular.js developer.

Answer (score 1):

plnkr is very good and flexible, I would go for it, as for AngularJS questions you can get some ideas from articles like this one: http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/ I believe that a skilltest about two-way data binding and scope inheritance would be valueable, maybe resource/animation functionalities - but that depends on the work profile i.e. I don't use animation at all in company projects but in private project I do it heavily with famo.us use